# glib for mac os 10.6 snow leopard

Tags: objective-c, c, osx-snow-leopard, gnome, glib

am developing one dictionary for mac os 10.6. Am not able to locate glib.h. can i get this as a library or framework. am confused very much. please give me your valuable solution.

Note: i want to use GSList from glib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install it using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or download the source code and install manually. Or if you're developing a cocoa aplication I'm sure the framework has it's own list structures, it would be better to use the native ones.

Comment: thanks zeppelin....i already have a code implemented using glib(for linux). just i need to develop GUI(wrapper) for deployment. if i download & install it manually for development, later can i install & run the application independently on other mac machines ???

Comment: Compile glib statically and link it to your application. This way you won't depend on the existence of glib on target machines.